# string split issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just started writing JavaScript/Angular and can't seem to figure out why this ain't working.  I am trying to split a textarea's string into an array on the `\n` character inside a controller using `$scope.mytext.split("\n")` and I keep getting:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have also tried `ng-split='\n'` which works fine for text input, but doesn't seem to work for textarea.

Some guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have `ng-model="mytext"`? Where is `$scope.mytext.split("\n")` located within your controller?

Comment: You should post a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your error makes me believe that `mytext` is not an object where `split` is defined. Can you see what's in that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So going off the little information you gave us, I came up with the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yqpv7qq/)

This takes in a `<textarea>` input, binding it to `<ng-model>`, and then performing the split function to obtain and array based on where a `\n` is. Such that,

```
 $scope.myModel = {
        textarea: null,
        newTextarea: null
    };

    $scope.splitTextArea = function(input) {
        var newInput = input.split("\n");
        $scope.myModel.newTextarea = newInput;
    };
```

Comment: SOLVED:

Thanks for your response @tjb, following your fiddle  it seems that by passing the data to the controller only when button is clicked makes the difference, rather than accessing it through the $scope. Makes more sense this way, although other ng-model data is directly available using $scope, like radio button selections, input box data (which works well using ng-split=",").  My guess is that a test for undefined might have been necessary before calling split, if I were to use my original code.  In future I will endeavor to provide a clearer description of the problem.

Comment: @ybisrael no problem! Glad to help. Please accept my answer if it answered your question :)